# Writing a Polar Equation for the Graph of an Implicit Cartesian Equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, plane-curves, polar-coordinates

> If $(x^2+y^2)^3=4x^2y^2,$ then $r=\sin 2\theta$ for some $\theta$.

Using $r^2=x^2+y^2, x=r\cos\theta,y=r\sin\theta$, it's easy to get $r^2=\sin^22\theta$.
But I don't know what to do next, since $r$ could be negative in $r=\sin2\theta.$

Actually  the original problem is to show that the affine variety $V((x^2+y^2)^3-4x^2y^2)$ is contained in the four-leaved rose, whose polar equation is certainly $r=\sin 2\theta$. (Exercise 7(b), section 1.2, *Ideals, Varieties and Algorithms*, 3rd edition, David Cox etc.)

Comment: I assume it's the standard parametrization that $r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$.  In that case, if you end up with $r^2 = \sin^2{2\theta}$, there isn't any concern of $r$ being negative when you take the square root, since by definition $r$ is positive.  Thus $r$ is the positive solution to $\sqrt{\sin^2{2\theta}}$, so indeed $r = \sin{\phi}$ for some $\phi$ (where that $\phi = 2\theta$).  If this makes sense, I'd be happy to turn it into a full answer.

Comment: If we use one of the conventions (when $r$ is negative, reflect in the origin), the $r=\pm \sin 2\theta$ just traces out the figure twice.

Comment: @jamaicanworm, yes, $r$ must be positive, but not so $\sin2\theta$. The correct solution is $r=|\sin2\theta|$.

Comment: @Kou: If we decide that when $r<0$, the curve is not defined (which is one convention), then $r=\sin 2\theta$ has two leaves, not four.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Well, I have put the original problem in my question. Did you see it? "to show that the affine variety..."

Comment: @AndréNicolas Could you explain that why $r=\sin 2\theta$ has two leaves when $r<0$?

Comment: @jamaicanworm The real original problem: Now argue carefully that $V((x^2+y^2)^3-4x^2y^2)$ is contained in the four-leaved rose. This is trickier than it seems since r can be negative in $r=\sin2\theta$.

Comment: @Kou: To repeat, there are two common conventions: (i) if $f(\theta)<0$, then the curve $r=f(\theta)$ is not defined at $\theta$ and (ii) if $f(\theta)<0$, find the point $(|f(\theta)|,\theta)$ and reflect it across the origin, or equivalently rotate $180$ degrees. Let $f(\theta)=\sin 2\theta$.  Under convention (ii), we get $4$ leaves. Under convention (i), as $\theta$ travels $0$ to $90$, we get one leaf. In $(90,180)$, not defined, since there $\sin 2\theta$ is negative.  In $[180, 270]$, new leaf. In $(270,360)$, not defined.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thanks! I get it!

Comment: @Kou: So to sum up, unless you use convention (ii), $r=\sin 2\theta$ is not the four-leaved rose. If you want to use convention (i), then the response of Gerry Myerson is the right one. By the way, in lots of places you will see $r=\sin 2\theta$ called the four-leaf rose. That's because convention (ii) is quite commonly used.

Comment: @AndréNicolas But how to get $r=\sin 2\theta$ from that equation including $x$ and $y$, if we use convention (ii)? What is the trick here?

Comment: @Kou: Sorry for delay, I was away. Make the usual substitution. We get $r^6=4r^4\cos^2\theta\sin^2\theta=r^2\sin^2 2\theta$. Cancel the $r^4$. Technically, we can't do that, for we are missing the solution $r=0$. But $r=0$, $\theta=$ anything is one of the infinitely many addresses of the origin. The origin will turn out to be also on $r^2=\sin 2\theta$, so we will pick it up. If $r$ is allowed to be negative, then $r=\pm|\sin 2\theta|$. The curve $r=|\sin 2\theta|$ traces out the rose. The curve $r=-|\sin 2\theta|$ traces out the same rose. The end.

Comment: @Kou: the polar equation $r^2=\sin^2{2\theta}$ or $r=\pm\sin{2\theta}$ is, by symmetry ($\pi$-periodicity), geometrically equivalent to $r=|\sin{2\theta}|$. However, by an angle-doubling formula, this actually has period $\pi/2$, thus rising from and falling back to zero identically within each quadrant, to give the four-petaled shape. See my post below for more explanation. (I corrected my earlier mistake in the power or $r$, a remnant of which you see in my discussion of what would happen if we had $r=|\sin{2\theta}|^p$ for $p>0$ other than $1$, and in the blue curve for $p=1/3$ of my plot.)

Answer (score 9):

Allowing $r$ to take both nonnegative and negative values, the graphs of $r=\sin2\theta$ and $r=-\sin2\theta$ (on $0\le\theta<2\pi$) are identical—they contain the same set of geometric points in the plane—though they are traced out differently.  For $r=\sin2\theta$, as $\theta$ increases from $0$ to $2\pi$, the graph traces the first quadrant petal, then the fourth quadrant petal, then the third quadrant petal, and finally the second quadrant petal.  For $r=-\sin2\theta$, as $\theta$ increases from $0$ to $2\pi$, the graph traces the third quadrant petal, then the second quadrant petal, then the first quadrant petal, and finally the fourth quadrant petal.

*edit* Here's what I mean:

[image: animation of the two graphs plotting simultaneously]

Since the sets of points in the plane described by $r=\sin2\theta$ and $r=-\sin2\theta$ are identical, giving only one of them is sufficient to describe the same set of points as $(x^2+y^2)^3=4x^2y^2$.  That's what lets us go from $r^2=\sin^22\theta$ and its equivalent of $r=\pm\sin2\theta$ to only $r=\sin2\theta$.

Answer (score 8):

If $x=r\cos(\theta)$ and $y=r\sin(\theta)$, then $(x^2+y^2)^3=4x^2y^2$ becomes
$$
r^2=\sin^2(2\theta)
$$
as you say. However, note that the curve $r=\sin(2\theta)$ is symmetric through the origin since $\sin(2(\theta+\pi))=\sin(2\theta)$, so it is the same as $r=-\sin(2\theta)$. In other words, it doesn't matter whether you take $+$ or $-$.

$\hskip{4cm}$ [image: four-leafed clover]

Comment: Nice graphic. May I ask how you generated it?

Comment: @bgins: It was generated entirely using Mathematica 8.

Answer (score 1):

On the variety $V\left((x^2+y^2)^3-(2xy)^2\right)$,
in polar coordinates we have
$$
r^6=(x^2+y^2)^3=(2xy)^2=r^4\sin^2{2\theta}
$$
or
$$
r^2=\sin^2{2\theta}
\quad\implies\quad
r=\pm\sin2\theta
$$
(we can ignore the "trivial" algebraic solution $r=0$ for all $\theta$
since it is geometrically recovered for $\theta\in\pi\mathbb{Z}$).
Now $\sin{2\theta}$ has period $\pi$
(furnishing the same magnitude for $r$ at antipodal points),
the curve has point symmetry through the origin,
allowing us to discard the sign and consider only $r\in[0,1]$.
But
$$
\sin^2{2\theta}=\frac{1-\cos{4\theta}}{2}
$$
has period $\frac{\pi}{2}$, vanishes at the axes or "cardinal" directions,
and has its maxima of $1$ when $\cos{4\pi}=-1$, i.e. at $\theta=\frac{\pi}{4}+k\frac{\pi}{2}$.
This explains why the polar equation for the solution can take the forms
$$
r=\left|\sin{2\theta}\right|
=\left(\sin^2{2\theta}\right)^\frac{1}{2}
=\left(\frac{1-\cos{4\theta}}{2}\right)^\frac{1}{2}
$$
and why it gives us a four-leaved rose.

Qualitatively, the result is the same
with any positive power $r=|\sin{2\theta}|^p$,
but the petal thickness and area and
the attenuation of the maximum radius
all vary inversely with $p$.

Plotted with [sage](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/sage/plot/plot.html#sage.plot.plot.polar_plot) ([online](http://sagenb.org/)), here is
the solution $r^2=\sin^2{2\theta}$ (with the power $p=1$) in red,
with another curve $r^6=\sin^2{2\theta}$ (with $p=\frac{1}{3}$) in blue
to illustrate the effect of $p$.

```
t=var('t')
(polar_plot(abs(sin(2*t))^(2/2), (t, 0, 2*pi), color='red')
+polar_plot(abs(sin(2*t))^(2/6), (t, 0, 2*pi), color='blue')).show()
```

[image: True solution in blue, simpler curve in red.]

Finally, as a refresher, a good way to remember or derive
the angle-doubling step above is from the two equations
$$
\begin{matrix}
\cos^2t&+&\sin^2t&=&1\\
\cos^2t&-&\sin^2t&=&\cos2t.
\end{matrix}
$$
Adding or subtracting (and dividing by two) then yields
$$
\cos^2t = \frac{1+\cos2t}{2}
\qquad
\text{or}
\qquad
\sin^2t = \frac{1-\cos2t}{2}
$$
respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Avoiding the issue entirely: 
$$r = \sin(2\theta) = 2\sin\theta\cdot \cos\theta$$ 
$$r^3 = 2(r\sin\theta)(r\cos\theta)$$

$$x = r\cos\theta$$
$$y = r\sin\theta$$

$$r^3 =2xy$$

$$r = (x^2 + y^2)^{\frac 12}$$

$$(x^2+y^2)^{\frac 32} =2xy$$
$$(x^2+y^2)^3=4x^2y^2$$