# Computing $\int_{|z|=1}|z-1|\cdot|dz|$.

Tags: complex-analysis, integration

I'm trying to teach myself some complex integration. I'm doing some exercises, and want to compute
$$
\int_{|z|=1}|z-1|\cdot |dz|.
$$
I parametrize with $z(t)=e^{it}$ on the interval $(0,2\pi)$, so $z'(t)=ie^{it}$, so $|z'(t)|=1$, and I believe the integral is then equivalent to
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}|e^{it}-1|dt.
$$
How can I deal with that pesky absolute value sign to finish the computation? Thank you.

Comment: For every real number $t$, $|\mathrm e^{\mathrm it}-1|=2|\sin(t/2)|$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the integrand in your second expression, you want to use
$$|e^{it}-1|=|(\cos(t)+i\sin(t))-1|=$$
$$=\sqrt{(\cos(t)-1)^2+\sin^2(t)}=\sqrt{\cos^2(t)-2\cos(t)+1+\sin^2(t)}=$$
$$=\sqrt{2(1-\cos(t))}=\sqrt{2(1-\cos(t))}=\sqrt{4\ \sin^2\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)}=2\sin\left(\frac{t}{2}\right),$$
in your interval.

Comment: @anon: >in your interval.

Comment: Whoops nevermind.

Comment: @Nick: As the other answers indicate, you are missing an absolute value sign (as $\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$).

Comment: @JavaMan: Well, as I already said to username anon, I intended to make a statement for the relevant integral $[0,2\pi]$, for which the $\sin$-expression is positive. But if it bothers you, please go ahead and change it.

Answer (score 4):

Using the [half-angle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Double-.2C_triple-.2C_and_half-angle_formulae) formula for sine, which can be easily derived from the double angle formula for cosine (for example at the end of [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/104163/writing-a-polar-equation-for-the-graph-of-an-implicit-cartesian-equation/106811#106811)), we have:
$$
\begin{array}{}
|e^{it}-1|
&=&|\cos{t}+i\sin{t}-1|\\
&=&\sqrt{(\cos{t}-1)^2+\sin^2{t}}\\
&=&\sqrt{1+\cos^2{t}+\sin^2{t}-2\cos{t}}\\
&=&\sqrt{2(1-\cos{t})}\\
&=&\sqrt{4\frac{1-\cos{t}}{2}}\\
&=&2\sqrt{\sin^2{\frac{t}{2}}}\\
&=&2\left|\sin\frac{t}{2}\right|
\end{array}
$$
as Didier suggested.
Then use $2\int_0^{\pi}2\sin\frac{t}2dt=8\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin{u}~du$ (with $u=\frac{t}2$ and $du=\frac12dt$) to get $8$.

Comment: @Dedede: you're welcome, but I forgot to unstretch the $t$ axis when integrating (giving another factor of two!). I think it's correct now.