# General Cartesian/Rectangular Equation for Polar Rose ($r=\sin(k\theta)$)

Tags: trigonometry, graphing-functions, polar-coordinates

How do I convert the Polar Equation $r=\sin(k \theta)$ to Cartesian Equation?

I understand that $r^2=x^2+y^2$ and that $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$, but no matter how I try to arrange them it seems that I can never cancel out both r and $\theta$.

I've looked at [Writing a Polar Equation for the Graph of an Implicit Cartesian Equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/104163/writing-a-polar-equation-for-the-graph-of-an-implicit-cartesian-equation) and several mathematics sites on the internet and some videos by PatrickJMT on this, but my knowledge of trigonometry is limited, and I haven't been able to find any sort of a way to get a general cartesian equation for a polar rose.

Also, the Parametric equations for polar rose such that $r=\cos(k\theta)$ are $x=\cos(k t)\sin t$ and $y=\cos(k t)\cos t$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you expect to write it as $y=f(x)$, it will not happen as the graph is certainly not a function, neither on $x$ nor on $y$.

What you can do is express the equation parametrically. As
$$
x=r\cos\theta,\ \ y=r\sin\theta,
$$
you can write
$$
(x(t),y(t))=(\sin kt\,\cos t,\ \sin kt\,\sin t), \ \ t\in[0,2\pi]
$$

Comment: I understand that it isn't a function.  Is there a way to write it as multiple functions?

Comment: You could. You would have two functions for each petal; $2k$ functions in total. Not sure why you would want them, though.

Comment: What would those functions look like?

Comment: That's the thing. You need to solve $x=\sin kt\,\sin t$. Here: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%5Bx%3D%3DSin%5B2t%5DSin%5Bt%5D%2Ct%5D is what it looks like for the case $k=2$.

Comment: I see.  You would have to restrict the domain somehow.  Thanks for all of your help.

Answer (score 3):

Each one may be solved individually: 
[Polar to cartesian form of $ r = \sin(2\theta)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/784377/polar-to-cartesian-form-of-r-sin2-theta)

$$r = \sin(2\theta) = 2\sin\theta\cdot \cos\theta$$ 
$$r^3 = 2(r\sin\theta)(r\cos\theta)$$

$$x = r\cos\theta$$
$$y = r\sin\theta$$

$$r^3 =2xy$$

$$r = (x^2 + y^2)^{\frac 12}$$

$$(x^2+y^2)^{\frac 32} =2xy$$
$$(x^2+y^2)^3=4x^2y^2$$

See Also: [Polar to cartesian form of r=cos(2θ)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1929330/polar-to-cartesian-form-of-r-cos2%CE%B8/1929354#1929354)

Answer (score 1):

For k=2 squaring,

$$ r^2 = x^2 + y^2 =  \sin^2 (2 \theta )  = 4  \,\sin^2 \theta \cos^2 \theta = 4 \,x^2 \, y^2 / (x^2 + y^2) $$.

For integral k such conversion using De Moivre expansion is possible . For non-integral k an infinite series results. The domain is restricted due to circular trig functions.

Answer (score 1):

The polar rose $r=\sin\left(a\theta\right)$ for odd $a$ values, can be written as $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=\sin\left(a\left(\arcsin\left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right)\right)\right)$.  For even $a$ values, it can be written as $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=±\sin\left(a\left(\arcsin\left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right)\right)\right)$.