# Polar to cartesian form of r=cos(2θ)

Tags: trigonometry

This is possible for $r=\sin(2θ)$: [Polar to cartesian form of $ r = \sin(2\theta)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/784377/polar-to-cartesian-form-of-r-sin2-theta)

Surely there is some trig identity that may substitute for $cos(2θ)$ and allow for a similar coordinates transfer. What is the cartesian form of $\cos(2\theta)$?

I found something remotely similar: 
$$\cos(2θ) = \cos^2θ − \sin^2θ = 2 \cos^2θ − 1 = 1 − 2 \sin^2θ$$
(source: http://www.math.ups.edu/~martinj/courses/fall2005/m122/122factsheet.pdf)

However they all use a squared form of sin or cos, which I am not certain how to convert into Cartesian coordinates.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @copper.hat the equation is written in polar form. What is the cartesian form of this equation?

Comment: Related: polar to cartesian form of r=tan2θ http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1929390/polar-to-cartesian-form-of-r-tan2%CE%B8/1929416#1929416

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All polar to Cartesian / Cartesian to polar transformations derive from these simple rules

$r^2 = x^2 + y^2\\
x = r \cos \theta\\
y = r \sin \theta$

$r  = cos 2\theta$  the 4 petaled rose.  If it had an elegant form in Cartesian we would teach it.  It will likely be a cubic or quartic equation.

$r  = \cos^2 \theta - sin^2 \theta\\
r^3 = r^2 \cos^2 \theta - r^2 \sin^2 \theta\\
(x^2+y^2)^{\frac32} = x^2 - y^2\\
(x^2 + y^2)^3 = (x^2 - y^2)^2$

I suppose we could keep multiplying that out.  But I think that looks pretty elegant.

Comment: I just wanted to add that it is possible to scale the cartesian equation by dividing the equation so that it is equal to a constant: $\frac{(x^2-y^2)^2}{(x^2+y^2)^3}=constant$

Answer (score 2):

By the [double angle formulas](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Double-AngleFormulas.html),
$$r=\cos(2\theta)=\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta=\frac{x^2}{r^2}-\frac{y^2}{r^2}=\frac{x^2-y^2}{r^2}$$
This leads, because $r^2=x^2+y^2$, to
$$x^2-y^2=r^3=\left(x^2+y^2\right)^{3/2}$$
You should then be able to square, multiple terms out and find the equation in implicit form.

[Wolfram Alpha gives several approximations for $y=f(x)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=graph+solution+of+x%5E4%2By%5E4-2x%5E2y%5E2%3Dx%5E6+%2B+y%5E6+%2B+3x%5E4y%5E2+%2B+3y%5E4x%5E2), but none of them are nice. I'd recommend sticking to polar coordinates when analyzing this function.

Comment: I squared:$(x^2-y^2)^2=(x^2+y^2)^3$ however, further expansion seems fruitless: $x^4-2x^2y^2+y^4=x^6+3x^4y^2+3x^2y^4+y^6$

Comment: @Dale You won't get an equation of the form $y=f(x)$; this is also the case in the question you linked to. Transforming from polar to Cartesian with functions involving trigonometric functions often leaves you with expressions like this.