# Polar to cartesian form of $r=\tan(2θ)$

Tags: trigonometry

I have attempted converting $r=\tan(2θ)$ to cartesian coordinates:

$$r=\frac{2\sin(θ)\cos(θ)}{\cos^2(θ)-\sin^2(θ)}$$
$$r=\frac{2r\sin(θ)r\cos(θ)}{r^2\cos^2(θ)-r^2\sin^2(θ)}$$

$r^2 = x^2 + y^2\\
x = r \cos \theta\\
y = r \sin \theta$

$$r=\frac{2xy}{x^2-y^2} $$
$$(x^2+y^2)^{1/2}=\frac{2xy}{x^2-y^2} $$
$$(x^2+y^2)= \left(\frac{2xy}{x^2-y^2}\right)^2 $$
This [doesn't graph properly](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(x%5E2%2By%5E2)%3D(%5Cfrac%7B2xy%7D%7Bx%5E2-y%5E2%7D)%5E%7B2%7D) on Wolfram Alpha, so I must have made a mistake.

Comment: When in doubt, use [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator). It is very good at plotting implicit curves, and it shows that your derivation is correct.

Comment: use that $$x=r\cos(\phi),y=r\sin(\phi),r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$ and i got the same as you.

Comment: Notice $r$ is not necessarily positive.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Are you saying something different than the accepted answer?

Comment: Yes, the accepted answer is actually wrong, and the polar plot $r=\tan(2\theta)$ is indeed, the **full** graph of $x^2+y^2=(2xy/(x^2-y^2))^2$, though it's not completely obvious.

Comment: By the way, here is how to ask WA: [cartesian](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+(x%5E2%2By%5E2)%3D(%5Cfrac%7B2xy%7D%7Bx%5E2-y%5E2%7D)%5E%7B2%7D), [polar](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+r%3Dtan(2theta)+for+theta+from+-pi+to+pi). Remove the straight lines from the polar plot (they appear because of jumps at tangent discontinuities)

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I think your explanation is completely obvious now that the function is graphed correctly. Apparently the mistake I made leading to this quesiton was improper plotting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an answer, but an illustration.

For $\theta$ from $-\pi/4$ to $\pi/4$, you get the blue branch. It starts on the left for negative $\theta$. Because of the $\pi/2$ periodicity of $r$, the other branches are found by rotating the first by $\pi/2$ repeatedly.

[image]