# Polar to cartesian form of $ r = \sin(2\theta)$

Tags: trigonometry, polar-coordinates

As title describes, I was wondering how I would put this into Cartesian form, from polar.

All I have is $ r = \sin(2\theta)$.

I'm not really sure what to do, I've been trying to find similar problems on the internet to no avail (at least with an explanation), nor can I figure it out myself. Any help would be great.

Comment: If you don't know that $\sin(2\theta)=2\sin\theta\cos\theta$, then you need to review trigonometry.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Really? Don't you think that was a little harsh?  There are nicer ways to suggest something.

Comment: Suggesting reviewing trigonometry is harsh?  Or saying it appears that someone doesn't know a certain fact is harsh?  It does appear likely that the poster didn't know that, since otherwise that would be among the first things to come to mind.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1929330/polar-to-cartesian-form-of-r-cos2%CE%B8/1929340?noredirect=1#comment3960822_1929340

Comment: Inverse Question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/104163/writing-a-polar-equation-for-the-graph-of-an-implicit-cartesian-equation

Comment: r=sin(4θ): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1930325/polar-to-cartesian-form-of-r-sin4%CE%B8

Answer (score 4):

$r = \sin(2\theta) = 2\sin\theta\cdot \cos\theta \to r^3 = 2(r\sin\theta)(r\cos\theta)$. Then use:

$x = r\cos\theta$, and $y = r\sin\theta$, and $r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ to finish.

Comment: thank you! didn't think about multiplying it by r^2

Answer (score 2):

$$r = \sin(2\theta) = 2\sin\theta\cdot \cos\theta$$ 
$$r^3 = 2(r\sin\theta)(r\cos\theta)$$

$$x = r\cos\theta$$
$$y = r\sin\theta$$

$$r^3 =2xy$$

$$r = (x^2 + y^2)^{\frac 12}$$

$$(x^2+y^2)^{\frac 32} =2xy$$
$$(x^2+y^2)^3=4x^2y^2$$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrifolium