# Polar to cartesian form of r=sin(4θ)?

Tags: polar-coordinates

The [Polar to cartesian form of $ r = \sin(2\theta)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/784377/polar-to-cartesian-form-of-r-sin2-theta) is fairly simple.
What is the Cartesian form of the polar equation r=sin(4θ)?

[edit]
$$r=4sin(θ)cos(θ)(cos(θ)^2-sin(θ)^2)$$, so $$r^5=4rsin(θ)rcos(θ)(r^2cos(θ)^2-r^2sin(θ)^2)$$,so $$r^5=4xy(x^2-y^2)$$, so $$(x^2+y^2)^{5/2}=4xy(x^2-y^2)$$, so $$(x^2+y^2)^{5}=(4xy(x^2-y^2))^{2}$$, so $$(x^2+y^2)^{5}=16x^2y^2(x^2-y^2)^{2}$$

Comment: Did you try anything ?

Comment: Do the same thing they did in the other example. You just have to apply an identity twice.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I searched google for $sin(4\theta)$ with no success. The identities Fourier Tranform supplied were what I was seeking.

Comment: Eventually you could write the right hand side term as

$$16x^2y^2(x^2-y^2)^2$$

But it's just aesthetics.

Comment: Googling sin(4theta) returned three good hits.

Comment: @YvesDaoust apparently using the symbol θ instead of spelling theta makes a difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\rho=\sin 4\theta=2\sin2\theta\cos2\theta=4\sin\theta\cos\theta(\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta)=\frac{4xy(x^2-y^2)}{\rho^4},$$ hence

$$(x^2+y^2)^5=(4xy(x^2-y^2))^2,$$

$$x^{10}+10x^4y^6+32x^4y^4+5x^2y^8-16x^2y^6+y^{10}+10y^4x^6+5y^2x^8-16y^2x^6=0.$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

$$\sin(4\theta) = 2\sin(2\theta)\cos(2\theta)$$

Then again you may use

$$\sin(2\theta) = 2\sin\theta\ \cos\theta$$

and

$$\cos(2\theta) = \cos^2\theta - \sin^2\theta$$

Can you go on?

Comment: I edited into the question a proposed solution.

Comment: @Dale Great! It seems correct to me!

Comment: Why won't wolfram graph it? http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+(x%5E2%2By%5E2)%5E%7B5%7D%3D(4xy(x%5E2-y%5E2))%5E%7B2%7D

Comment: @Dale It cannot plot an equation!

Comment: It plotted this equation: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+(x%5E2%2By%5E2)%5E3%3D4x%5E2y%5E2 for $r=sin(2*\theta)$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: use that $$\cos(4\theta)=\sin (\theta )+\cos ^4(\theta )-6 \sin ^2(\theta ) \cos ^2(\theta )$$